# Problema DropDown menu bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho meu menu dropdown

Mas sempre tenho que dar 2 clicks para ele abrir o menu, gostaria que no primeiro click ele já abrice...

Teria como ter ele sem o elemento `<a`?

esse é meu código:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cadastro <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#/clientes">Cliente</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
        </ul>

            </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Quais JavaScripts foram inclusos juntamente com esse HTML?

Comment: jquery seguido de bootstrap.js ah, também uso angularjs...até pensei que era isso, que toda vez que clico ele tenta ir até o link #, por isso perguntei se teria como não colocar o elemento a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem duas maneiras:

### 1. Prevenir o comportamento padrão do `dropdown-toggle`

Adicione o seguinte no seu código:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    return false;
});
```

### 2. Usando outra classe

Troque `dropdown-toggle` por `dropdown-menu`.

Comment: usei só dropdown-menu e deu certo =D

Comment: funciona com o dropdown-submenu também, vlw muito @CiganoMorrisonMendez